# How to call async function from within another component in reac js redux web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have the code below but it gives error:

```js
const fetchData = (name) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchDataRequest());
        
    await axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        data = response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        data = [];
      });
    return data;
  };
};
```

Component code:

```
import {fetchData} from "../../Actions/userActions"
import {useEffect, useState, forwardRef} from "react";

export const ParentModal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  console.log(" type:" + typeof fetchData );
    
  const [initialLoading, setinitialLoading] useState(true);

  useEffect (async () => {
    fetchData("foo").then(async (res) => {
      console.log("result arrived!!!");
    });
  }, []);
    
  return (initialLoading) ? (
    <mui.CircularProgress className="smloader" />
    ReactDOM.createPortal (
    <div>
    <ChildModal
    open={open}
    />
    ....
```

But it gives this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0,
> _Serviceworkers_redux_Actions_userActions__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__fetchData(...).then
> is not a function

`fetchData` is a call to remote API. What I want to accomplish is that I want to render `ChildModal` only after data from remote API has arrived in `ParentModal`.

Note that console prints: type: function

but result arrived!!! never printed.

Actions are thunk actions and reducers. Most code is removed as actual code is much bigger. Just cut down to minimum to solve the problem.

Comment: What is `data` in `fetchData` that is returned? It doesn't appear to be declared. Is `fetchData` supposed to be an action, e.g. a Thunk action? This all looks like rather incomplete code. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]? What is `hooks` for example?

Comment: data is a array of objects

Comment: updated my post.

Comment: I see. Has an answer here addressed the issue of calling the `fetchData` function and chaining from it?

Comment: Thanks I will check on it and will post comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetchData function returns a thunk (a function that returns a function) instead of a promise. To call a thunk, you need to call it with `dispatch`

```
import { fetchData } from '../../Actions/userActions';

export const ParentModal = hooks.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
  const [initialLoading, setinitialLoading] = hooks.useState(true);

  hooks.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData("foo")).then(() => {
      console.log("result arrived!!!");
      setinitialLoading(false);
    });
  }, [dispatch]);
    
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {initialLoading && <mui.CircularProgress className="smloader" />}
      {!initialLoading && ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <ChildModal open={open} />,
        document.getElementById('modal-root')
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
```

ps. set the initialLoading flag to false in the `.then()` callback in order for the ChildModal to be rendered after the data has arrived

official Redux documentation: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it appears that `fetchData` is an asynchronous action creator, e.g. a Thunk action, and as such it needs to be *dispatched* to the store. In the code you've shared you are only calling the first function, and never the returned function that returns a Promise object to chain from.

It's also generally considered anti-pattern to mix `async/await` with Promise chains. Use one or the other.

The `useEffect` hook callback function also cannot be an `async` funcion, it must be a regular synchronous function.

```js
const fetchData = (name) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchDataRequest());

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    return [];
  };
};
```

```js
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData } from "../../Actions/userActions";

export const ParentModal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData("foo"))
      .then((res) => {
        console.log({ res });
      });
  }, [dispatch]);

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, modify your fetchData as i see either an incomplete code or some syntax error.

Modify fetchData function

```js
// i'll maintain same syntax for easy understanding 
const fetchData = (name) => {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchDataRequest());

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = response.data;
      return data; // return the data from your api if any, to be used when this function is called
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return [];
    }
  };
};
```

2. call the function and check if there's any return data

```js
import {
  fetchData
} from "../../Actions/userActions";

export const ParentModal = hooks.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [initialLoading, setInitialLoading] = hooks.useState(true);

  hooks.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData("foo")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("result arrived!!!");
        console.log({
          res
        }); // this should print the response into your console just so you see what returned from the function 
        setInitialLoading(false); // Set loading to false when data arrives
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        setInitialLoading(false); // Handle errors and set loading to false
      });
  }, []);

  return initialLoading ? ( <
    mui.CircularProgress className = "smloader" / >
  ) : (
    ReactDOM.createPortal( <
      div >
      <
      ChildModal open = {
        open
      }
      /> <
      /div>,
      // ...
    )
  );
});
```